# Find postgres I was connected to

Tags: macos, postgresql

I have done something rather dumb.

I got a new work machine and, for weeks (I know, I know) I have been connected to a version of postgres. Last night, the machine restarted and now I can't seem to flip on the correct version of postgres.

When I try to access the database using the same credentials as before, my machine claims that the user, postgres, doesn't exist. That can't be true, as I successfully logged in as that user and had done quite a bit of work.

My question: is there a way to find out where that database is on my filesystem somehow? I know I called the database "analysis_db" and I remember several of the tablenames.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Assuming there is a file somewhere with "analysis_db" in its name... `find / -iname "*analysis_db*" 2> /dev/null`

Comment: If there is, it's not being found :/